# Vulnerability is MSSQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

NOTE: this is not my application, it is part of an **intentionally vulnerable** training application.

I am doing a cyber security course and as part of assessing ataregt application I have leaked as ASP file that contains teh following query to an MSSQL DB on SQL Server 2000.

```
myUsrName = stripFilter(request.form("user"))
myUsrPassword = stripFilter(request.form("password"))

sSql = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomers where cust_name='" & myUsrName & "' and cust_password='"&myUsrPassword&"'"
```

What stands out a bit here (aside from user controlled input) is the second variable `myUsrPassword` is being passed without surrounding white space on either side of the `&`'s, whereas `myUsrName` has said whitespace.

I am trying to bypass some character filtering between the user and the query and need to know how this affects what is passed in. Ie, do I need to account for creating whitespace on my then malicious query.

What is the difference on this on the server side when this query is processed?

Comment: Hi @Sami it is a training application on a cyber security course. Edited for clarity

Comment: This is VBA code. Whitespace around operators (+, -, *, & etc) are optional. The whitespace is part of the code, not the (concatenated) strings.

Comment: Given what @SalmanA said, there will be no difference on the server side since the same query is sent to the server.

Comment: Perfect, cheers both

Comment: I understand that this is a training scenario but your training materials are approaching twenty years old if they're using Classic ASP and SQL Server 2000. If this course does not have more modern examples/software, I would recommend finding a different course.

Comment: @alroc. I realise how old it is and it is a pain! The course has a reputation for being out o date, but it's still the one to have to get into the pentest market unfortunately.